# python socket Errno 10060

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using python socket to connect to a server but *sometimes* I get this:

> error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

when I call the socket.connect method

```
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((self._ipv4address, host_port))
try:
    s.connect((dest_ip, dest_port))
except:
    raise
```

Why am I seeing this error? And how do I solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe it happens because the server did not properly respond after a period of time...

Comment: but I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the server (if that's what you mean), I'm trying to load a website, the website opens properly from the browser without using my program, the only problem with it is that its a little big.

Comment: are you sure it doesn't happen in you browser _sometimes_? as 10060 seems to be a timeout error, is it possible the server is very slow in accepting connection (busy boy) and your browser has higher timeout threshold? do you really need to bind socket to the local address? (I might think it _sometimes_ could be a reason.)

Comment: @tomasz I'm getting the same error when i try to connect to google, and the same happens when i don't bind the socket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to bind the socket (unless the remote server has an expectation of incoming socket) - it is extremely rare that this would actually be a requirement to connect.

Instead of using sockets to open a website, use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) if you need to twiddle forms. They manage cookies, sessions, page state, etc.. Much easier.

Also, if you fail to to connect.. don't give up! Try again, some sites can be pokey to respond. Some may not respond for a while depending - handle it better. Instead of just raising the error, wrap your connection method with an [exponential backoff](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Retry) decorator.

Comment: the exponential backoff seems to be working, didn't know about that pattern ... thanks a lot mate :)