# Python running on spyder 2.2.5

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to Python and trying to run attached code.

```
import urllib

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
print(url)
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

But I get an error below:

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/myname/Documents/Python Scripts/ex00.py', wdir=r'C:/Users/myname/Documents/Python Scripts')
https://www.google.com/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/myname/Documents/Python Scripts/ex00.py", line 5, in <module>
    sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib.py", line 437, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 1172, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Earlier I thought that it is may be because I am running the script from my office and VPN is causing issues. So I ran it from my home internet connection but no resolution :(

Comment: It does work for me... I use Spyder 2.3.0b3, but I agree that your problem is that Spyder is being blocked. Can you check your firewall?

Comment: Also, did you read this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456422/python-socket-errno-10060

Comment: I agree with @Roberto, most probably the problem lies in your firewall configuration. Try to give permission to `python.exe` (because Spyder is not detected as an application on Windows) to do external connections from your computer.